# Switching between different networks in Metamask using web3 or any other automated way

Tags: metamask, etherscan, bsc, binance

I have two different smartchains in Metamask wallet

1. ETH
2. BSC

Now I want to transfer money from one network to the other in the same wallet address either using web3.js or any other possible programmatic way.

Any suggestion how should I go ahead with it?

Comment: You cannot just move funds from one chain to another. For this, you will need a bridge contract that will lock the funds on one chain and give you funds on the other chain. There is also https://www.binance.org/en/bridge or Binance itself, you can try to use API to make it programmatic way.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there any way by which I can transfer coins from coinbase to metamask to a specific network in Metamask? If that can be achieved, it indirectly solves my problem

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an access to Coinbase as I'm not a US citizen. You can create a new post if you can't find this information on the Internet.